# Android Running app on reboot causing android default home screen not activate

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I have an app and I want it to run immediately whenever device got rebooted. To achieve this I added home and default category to MainActivity.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

However after doing this since default home screen is not launched it needs to click home button twice to go back to the home screen. I know that I could handle this by monitor home button click action like follow.

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    this.window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
}

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        //open defualt home screen intent
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

However, if user goes to somewhere else (let's say open setting from status bar) then click home button. This issue will happen again.

Therefore is there a way to avoid this? Maybe consider run default home screen at background when device get reboot but I  honestly don't know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setting yourself up as HOME means you're claiming to be a launcher app-  a replacement for the homescreen.  Having 2 launcher apps running at once confused the system.  Don't do that.  If you want to be launched on boot, use a BOOT_COMPLETE listener and launch an Activity from it.  The method you used only should be used if you're writing an alternative home screen or a kiosk app.

Comment: So my requirement is to write a kiosk app, which is why I implement the above code. But I also want to allow users to use as a normal device if they leave the app.  Therefore it brings to this question.
The BOOT_COMPLETE will only be triggered on broadcast Receiver and causing system stay on default home page for a few seconds which is something I don't want.

The only possible solution I could think of is to find a way run default home screen at background but haven' had any useful solution. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Is it a requirement that your app run as soon as the phone starts? If the answer to the previous question is no then consider using ***Lock Task Mode*** in lieu of your current implementation to create a kiosk app that allows the user to lock into the app and exit on certain conditions. Code example: [start lock task mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247919/activity-startlocktask-from-one-activity-to-another-activity)

Comment: @RanZhang does my comment work for you?

Comment: Sorry the answer is yes. I need to prevent user to see any another screen before my app starts running.